# DropDownList, List item then popullated from database

Tags: asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList, when the form is first opened it selects the first entry found in the database. What I want it to do is display "Select." But I don't want the "Select" message to hold any value towards my database (I don't want the system to think this is an option to edit into the database).

What I'm trying at the moment is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListEmployee" runat="server"  
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionHasChanged"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Fullname"  
                  DataValueField="Employee_ID" Width="214px">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
```

I have tried using:

```
dropdownList.DataBind();
dropdownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select"));
```

This solution kept setting "Select" into txt/data fields in which it did not belong, causing issues when trying to update, insert, or delete from database.

Also, how do I edit my posts so that it shows the code?

================ Code Behind File ================

```
namespace MyProject.Update
{
    public partial class UpdateEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SelectionHasChanged(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Retreive", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 7));
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListEmployee.SelectedValue.ToString());


            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    txt1.Text = (string)reader["1"];
                    txt2.Text = (string)reader["2"];
                    txt3.Text = (string)reader["3"];
                    txt4.Text = (string)reader["4"];
                    txt5.Text = (string)reader["5"];
                    txt6.Text = (string)reader["6"];
                    txt7.Text = (string)reader["7"];
                    txt8.Text = DropDownListEmployee.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }

                reader.Close();

            }

            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }


        protected void UpdateEmployeeBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Change", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 7));
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListEmployee.SelectedValue.ToString());



            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20));
            cmd.Parameters["@1"].Value = txt1.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20));
            cmd.Parameters["@2"].Value = txt2.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
            cmd.Parameters["@3"].Value = txt3_Address.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
            cmd.Parameters["@4"].Value = txt4.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.Char, 12));
            cmd.Parameters["@5"].Value = txt5.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.Char, 12));
            cmd.Parameters["@6"].Value = txt6.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            cmd.Parameters["@7"].Value = txt7.Text;


            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txtID.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value);
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I generally indent my code 4 spaces (or more) to get the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the AppendDataBoundItems attribute:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListEmployee" runat="server"  
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionHasChanged"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Fullname"  
                  DataValueField="Employee_ID" Width="214px"
                  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select" />
```

This will allow you to add the databound items to the list without affecting anything you declared prior.  Just make sure you add any items to the list **before** you call DataBind().

[ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx)

**ADDED**

Based on the code behind you pasted, I believe both ShankarSangoli and rudeovski ze bear have viable approaches for you.  You need to check to ensure the user has made a selection in the DropDownList, and either throw an error if they didn't or provide some default value.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate the selected value of the dropdownlist either on the client or server side before you insert it into database. I would suggest you to do it on the client side.

E.g. Using javascript/jquery you can check for the selected value.

```
if($("select[id*=DropDownListEmployee]").val() == "Select"){
   alert("Please select an employee);
   return false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
}
```

You can also check for selected value on the server side before inserting it into database.

Comment: sorry about that - I added to your answer instead of mine.  I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, it looks like you want to avoid the "select" item from going into the database.

So what you do is, in your submit event, you do a check to see if "DropDownListEmployee"'s selectedvalue != "Select".

You can also do this using javascript/jquery onclientclick of the submit button.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    if ($("#DropDownListEmployee").val() == "Select")
       // DO SOMETHING (or return false)
    else 
       return true;
});
```

in your codebehind button click event, do something like the following:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownListEmployee.SelectedValue == "Select")
        // DO SOMETHING
    else
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement the top solution, but I'm having issues... What I did was turn it into the following javascript and added it after the buttonClick and tried adding it before the buttonClick. '<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submitButton").click(function ()
 {     
 if (#DropDownListEmployee).val() == "Select") 
       // DO SOMETHING (or return false) 
 return false; 
    else         
 return true; 
 }); 
</script>'

Comment: Are you loading the JQuery library in your html?
In that code, you're missing the double quotes and the $ sign before $("#dropdownlistemployee").val()

Answer (score 0):

`dropdownList.DataBind(); dropdownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select"));` should theoretically work for you. The side effects you describe lead me to believe there's a lot of other funky stuff going on in your code. You should edit your post to include more of your code so that we can provide better answers.